# how to print ahuge number of documents in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, printing

i have a search page .my result is shown in gridview and there is a button named print all
i write a loop to get all paths of documents(images) from grid view and print all but when result number is about 20000 and above my website hanged 
i want to know away to divide these documents  or print these number of images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used itextsharp to add images on PDF file and download it